# Nginx Wave Framework API configuration issue - WARNING: Nginx HttpRewriteModule is not supported

Tags: php, web-services, ubuntu, nginx, web-frameworks

I have searched for a few days and tried various configurations through trial and error but I have not been able to correct my configuration. My specialty is in database design and development so server configuration has been challenging.

I am on a LEMP stack and I installed the Wave Framework. Wave is a PHP micro-framework that is built loosely following model-view-control architecture and factory method design pattern 
http://www.waveframework.com/wave/doc/index.htm

Surprisingly it's pretty easy to get on your server however I can't resolve one issue. On my server I added in the lines into my nginx config file the Wave suggested and I still get the warning "WARNING: Nginx HttpRewriteModule is not supported, Index Gateway and rewrite functionality will not work, this warning can be ignored if Index Gateway is not used"

Besides this I have been able to use a lot of the features of the Wave Framework and got a portion of my Model and Controller coded.

Please help, my config is pasted below.

nginx.conf

> user www-data;
>
> worker_processes 4;
>
> pid /run/nginx.pid;
>
> events {
>
> worker_connections 768; }
>
> http {
>
> sendfile on;
>
> tcp_nopush on;
>
> tcp_nodelay on;
>
> keepalive_timeout 65;
>
> types_hash_max_size 2048;
>
> rewrite_log on;
>
> include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
>
> default_type application/octet-stream;
>
> access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
>
> error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
>
> gzip on;
>
> gzip_disable "msie6";
>
> include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
>
> include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
>
> }

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
(i changed my domain name)

> server {
>          listen 80;
>
> ```
>  root /usr/share/nginx/www;
>
>    index index.php;   
>
>    server_name *.example.com;
> ```
>
> # This is for making sure that files in /resources/static/ folder don't get parsed with  PHP
>
> location ^~ /resources/static/ {
>
> ```
>   break;
> ```
>
> }
>
> error_page 404 /404.html;
>
> ```
>   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
>
>    location = /50x.html {
>
>          root /usr/share/nginx/www;
>
>    }
> ```
>
> # Rewrite that directs everything, except PHP to index file
>
> # Make sure you place this before your "location ~ .php$ {" for the server configuration.
>
> location / {
>
> ```
>   rewrite ^(.*)$ ./index.php last;
> ```
>
> }
>
> # Pass php scripts to the php engine
>
> ```
>    location ~ \.php$ {
>
>            try_files $uri =404;
>
>          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
>
>            fastcgi_index index.php;
>
>            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>
>            include fastcgi_params;
> ```
>
> }
>   }

http://www.example.com/tools/compatibility.php
(output for my domain - wave framework)

> SUCCESS: PHP is version 5.3.0 or above (running 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3)
>
> SUCCESS: PHP setting short_open_tag is enabled
>
> SUCCESS: PDO is supported
>
> SUCCESS: PDO MySQL is supported
>
> ...
>
> WARNING: Mcrypt PHP extension is not supported, this is optional and used only when API requests are made with www-crypt-input and www-crypt-output requests
>
> SUCCESS: Zip is supported
>
> SUCCESS: FTP is supported
>
> WARNING: Memcache is not supported, this can be ignored if you do not intend to support Memcache as a caching layer
>
> SUCCESS: GD Graphics Library is supported
>
> SUCCESS: Nginx server is used
>
> WARNING: Nginx HttpRewriteModule is not supported, Index Gateway and rewrite functionality will not work, this warning can be ignored if Index Gateway is not used
>
> SUCCESS: /filesystem/ is writable
>
> SUCCESS: /filesystem/cache/ is writable
>
> ...
>
> SUCCESS: /filesystem/data/ is writable

I am not worried about the other warnings beyond the HttpRewriteModule 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I (with help) answered my own question. Anyone who tries Wave Framework with Nginx will encounter this (at least with 3.7.1 current release). Wave Framework has a bug with the Nginx HTTPrewriteModule and the config file the provide for you to implement into your Nginx config is wrong. Below is my etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default config file that works for me.

```
# this file is /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/default/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/default/error.log;

root /var/www/default;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # domain names of this vhost (important if there are more
    # than one vhost on the same IP:PORT combination)
server_name localhost mydomain.com alias.mydomain.com;

    # deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    # deny access to hidden files, that is the ones which names that start
    # with . (dot)
    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }

    # This is for making sure that files in /resources/static/ folder don't get parsed    with PHP
    location ^~ /resources/static/ {
            break;
    }

    # Uncomment to satisfy compatibility check for Nginx rewrite module
# (based on .htaccess delivered with Wave Framework)
#   location ~ compatibility\.php$ {
#       if ($query_string != rewrite_enabled) {
#           rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?rewrite_enabled break;
#       }
#       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#       fastcgi_index index.php;
#       include fastcgi_params;
#   }

location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
}

    # Uncomment if you have a custom 404 page
#error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
location ~ \.php$ {
#   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```